# If $A$ is decidable, then $A$ is true.

Tags: logic, decidability

Given is a statement $A$. Now I know the following for this particular statement:

> If $A$ is decidable, then $A$ is true.

What can you conclude about the truth value of $A$? Obviously, if $A$ is true, then $A$ is decidable.

It seems like the decidability of $A$ does not really change the outcome, so I would assume that the truth value of $A$ is actually already determined before I decide what it is (with a proof).

My problem with this question probably comes from the fact that I do not know much about logic, (un)decidability or the mathematical axioms mathematicians are working with.

Comment: What’s the context for this? You can’t really conclude anything. There are true undecidable statements. There are false undecidable statements. There are true decidable statements. You just know that if it’s decidable then it’s true and if it’s false then it’s undecidable.

Comment: I’m not sure you can conclude $A$ is true implies $A$ is decidable, but instead if $A$ is false, then $A$ is not decidable, I.e the contra positive

Comment: "Decidable" and "true" do not mean much without context. "Decidable" is a syntactic notion, and refers to whether the statement can be proven or disproven in a particular formal system. "True" is a semantic notion, that refers to interpretations; it refers to whether a particular interpretation makes the statement true (so we talk about "true in a model"). The assertion that "if $A$ is true then it is decidable" is actually quite false in general, and probably not accurate in your particular instance either.

Comment: In intuitionistic logic, "$A$ is decidable" is often treated as shorthand for $A \lor \lnot A$; and in this interpretation, it's easy to see that if $A$ is true then it is decidable.  (On the other hand, "$A$ is decidable implies $A$ is true" ends up being equivalent to $\lnot \lnot A$ instead of $A$.)

Comment: I think what Daniel said is what I meant. I should use modern terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to clear up some possibly confusing terminology: "decidable" is usually a term applied to *sets* of formulas, and not individual formulas themselves. In this usage, it means that there exists an algorithm to decide whether a formula is a member of the set. However, there is another usage -- typically older -- which I will assume you are referring to in this question. By the older usage, we say that $A$ is *decidable* in a logical system $\mathcal{L}$ (roughly, a set of axioms) if either $A$ or its negation $\lnot A$ is provable in $\mathcal{L}$. I will assume this usage for the remainder of the answer.

With this usage in mind for *decidable,* there are still two ambiguities left in your question. First,

> Now I know the following for this particular statement:

(1) Do you *know* it in the sense you have a proof, or we are just supposing it is true? And second,

> If $A$ is decidable, then $A$ is true

(2) when you say "$A$ is decidable" -- decidable in what logical system $\mathcal{L}$?

Depending on the answers to (1) and (2), there are some things we can say. A famous result is: if the answer to (2) is ZFC, and the answer to (1) is that not only do you claim this is true -- you have a proof of in ZFC! -- then we can actually conclude from your statement ("if $A$ is decidable, then $A$ is true)" that $A$ is itself true! This is a consequence of [Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem), which is closely related to Gödel's second incompleteness theorem. Löb's theorem states:

- If there is proof that "$A$ is provable" implies $A$, then there is a proof of $A$.

To apply it to your case: your statement is that if $A$ is decidable, then $A$ is true. It follows that if $A$ is provable, then $A$ is true (since decidability means either $A$ or $\lnot A$ is provable). So what Löb's theorem states is that the only way to *know* your statement (in a fixed logical system) is for $A$ itself to be known.

Comment: Just to make sure this is transparent to the reader. Yes I was talking about the simple kind of decidability where I just want to know if A can either shown to be true of false. And yes, I have a proof of the statement "A decidable, then A is true" :)

Comment: @questionmaster Got it! Thanks for clarifying.